# Qt add-in 1.2.4 visual studio 2013 bug

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/putmq.png)**PC**

- qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.5.1  and the 64bit version of it
- visual studio 2013 ultimate
- qt add-in 1.2.4
- windows 10 x64bit

**problem:**

when i create a qt project in vs and try to build it.

1- i get the error *Qt5Widgetsd.lib(Qt5Widgetsd.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86*'

**note: the installed version of qt is the 64bit**

2- the libraries and everything **qt** related isn't recognized in the IDE "uderlined red"

**things i did to try and solve this problem**
when i change the TARGET MACHINE to MachineX64 (/MACHINE:X64) instead of MachineX86 (/MACHINE:X86) (in project properties>linker>advanced) and the platform still as it was (win32)

vs recognize the qt things/libraries and the underlines goes, however when i build i get this error
*Debug\moc_shitstackoverflow.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'*

when i change platform to x64 
i get this error 
the following error occurred: there's no qt version assigned to this project for platform x64. please use the "change QT version" feature and choose avalid qt version for this platform

and every thing get underlined again

so on an another failed attempt i uninstalled the 64bit of qt version and installed the 32bit one.

when i tried to build a newly created project in vs (under the 32bit) the project succeeded in building, however everything qt related was underlined red and the IDE don't recognizes it.

note* running vcvarsall.bat through qt cmd didn't change the underlining issue in vs in any of those cases!

so please i need help to this problem.
i tried everything i have found on the internet, but nothing solved the problem
so i wrote this very detailed explanation of what i have gone through the past 48 hours!

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to change the platform of the project? (Right-click on the solution node, choose 'Configuration Manager', and create a new x64 platform for your project and, when prompted, the solution.)

Comment: Plus I would recommend a clean rebuild of the project after changing the platform toolset.

Comment: mr simon, i always create new project whenever i try to do any of those solutions.

Comment: mr cameron: tried and still the error message appear as if there is no qt 64bit installed

Comment: VS 2013 works poorly with native C++ projects. Also I noticed problems with qt add-in 1.2.4. Therefore I use and recommend to use VS2012 + add-in 1.2.3

Comment: mr Vladimir. so this means that there is almost no solution/workaround for this problem..?

Comment: And I am still using AddIn 1.2.3 with VS for debug purposes and most of times I use Qt Creator.

Comment: well "debug purposes" isn't something trivial after all, anyway does anyone have an idea about what will happen if i installed vs 2012 and used qt creator 5.5 ?
will it work or not due to compiler differences?